# DialogInterface.OnClickListener() does not exist in the type 'DialogInterface' Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to display a list into an AlertDialog. I'm getting an error on `DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {}`

Full code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.SetTitle("Select data");
        List<string> lstTest = new List<string>();
        lstTest.Add("Test1");
        lstTest.Add("Test2");
        lstTest.Add("Test3");
        lstTest.Add("Test4");
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sent, args) => { //Event here 
        });
        builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sent, args) => { //Event here 
        });
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SelectDialogSingleChoice, lstTest);
        builder.SetAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { });
        builder.Show();
```

Perhaps there's a better way to do this completely? Have I just missed something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting an error on DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {}

Beacuse **SetAdapter()** method not contains the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` in Xamarin Android . You can hold down `Ctrl` key and left Click this method , will see what content of it .

[image]

There are two types of passed parameters , one is **`IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener`** , and another is `EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>` .

**Therefore** , you can custom a `DialogClickEventArgs` to callback click event .

Code as follow :

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.SetTitle("Select data");
List<string> lstTest = new List<string>();
lstTest.Add("Test1");
lstTest.Add("Test2");
lstTest.Add("Test3");
lstTest.Add("Test4");
builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sent, args) => { //Event here 
});
builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sent, args) => { //Event here 
});
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, lstTest);
builder.SetAdapter(arrayAdapter, customDialogClickEventArgs);
builder.Show();

private void customDialogClickEventArgs(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Click item");
}
```

**If** want to use `IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener` , you need to inherit this for current activity :

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener{...}
```

Dialog code as follow :

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.SetTitle("Select data");
List<string> lstTest = new List<string>();
lstTest.Add("Test1");
lstTest.Add("Test2");
lstTest.Add("Test3");
lstTest.Add("Test4");
builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sent, args) => { //Event here 
});
builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sent, args) => { //Event here 
});
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, lstTest);
builder.SetAdapter(arrayAdapter, this);
builder.Show();

public void OnClick(IDialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Click item");
}
```

The effect :

[image]