# Error : Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'int'

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder abc = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.Activity);
            abc.SetTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.xyz));
            abc.SetCancelable(false);           
            abc.SetPositiveButton(GetString(Resource.String.OK), (s, args) => { });
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.row_listview_layout, list);
            abc.SetAdapter(arrayAdapter, customDialogClickEventArgs);            
            abc.Create();
            abc.Show();
```

In this below line when i am passing the list it is showing error that : Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'int'

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.row_listview_layout, list);

Comment: What is `row_listview_layout`? Move the cursor/caret over this identifer and hit the F12 key. What is the class you are seeing then? What is its namespace? And the file this class is residing in, what is the absolute path of that file (hover with the mouse pointer over the tab of that file in Visual Studio to see a tooltip with the file path, assuming the file displayed is an actual file and not just presenting some metadata)?

Comment: row_listview_layout is a custom layout which I have created (having listview) in the layout folder and I was trying to show that layout in an alert dialog box with some list

Comment: Okay, what is `ArrayAdapter<T>` then which you are using? Isn't it this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.widget.arrayadapter-1.-ctor ? Notice that in the constructors of this class the second parameter is almost always an `int` (with one constructor being an exception, but which doesn't seem to match your code anyways) .

Comment: for that only I am seeking a solution

Comment: I do understand your question and thanks for the efforts you are making to help me.
Is there any other alternative than ArrayAdapter<T> that can I use or is there any way that I can convert my list to int type, I have tried Typecasting as well

Comment: Check this example I am trying to do same thing :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161868/dialoginterface-onclicklistener-does-not-exist-in-the-type-dialoginterface-x

Comment: If you are trying the same thing, why are you not using `Android.Resource.Layout.SelectDialogSingleChoice` as the example you linked to? Maybe it would be a good idea to stick for now with the standard stuff and not trying to do your own custom stuff like "row_listview_layout" that you are unable to explain clearly and that leads you to wanting to do strange stuff like wanting to turn some collection of items into some number...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thank you so much for brainstorming for my issue really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code is working fine after replacing the layout file
From:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.row_listview_layout, list);
```

To :

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, list);
```